# jars added to WEB-INF/lib doesn't get recognized when I try to import them : says the package doesn't exist

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-commons, apache-commons-fileupload

I have added `org.apache.commons.fileupload` and `org.apache.commons.io` package into the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of my project based on google appengine. But when I try importing in the servlet files the compiler/IDE gives an error that this package doesn't exist. Why is that ?

The *jar* files added :

[image]

What can be the reason I am getting this error ? What should I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: First thing to try is cleaning/rebuilding the project.

Comment: @Anthony Grist tried but the problem persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also have to add them to your project's classpath.

for eclipse:

Right click the jar, select build path and add it to the build path, then try again.

for netbeans:

in the project properties window click libraries in the left panel. In the right panel add it to the compile classpath

Comment: if you notice the third jar `mail.jar` in the picture,I just dropped into the lib folder and for that everything works fine

Comment: well, I still suggest you try it.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: see my answer; right click the jar, select "build path...", select "add to build path".

Comment: I do not see that option in my IDE _(netbeans)_

Comment: I googled "add jar to classpath netbeans" and added what I found to my post. Maybe you have a different version, so it could be slightly different, but still, adding it to the compile classpath should do it. Maybe the netbeans help will tell you exactly how to add a jar to the compile classpath.

Comment: thanks a lot ! The problem is solved. But can you tell me how without adding _mail.jar_ to the compiler classpath , i didn't get any error ?

Answer (score 2):

General solution , whenever you get package does not exist then there are 2 things, 1- Its not at all present 2) its present but still the error is thrown.
The solution to this is to just add the jar to the classpath [so that your app finds it during compilation,execution)

I would suggest you to try Maven . Maven is a nice way by which you can organize this in a systematic way.

Answer (score 0):

If the IDE gives the problem then update the jars in IDE project class path :)