# Java project issue in import

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

I am very new to java.

I downloaded Netbeans 8.2 and Jdk 1.8 and installed both.

And opened one of the projects where I'm getting three import statement issue.

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.diskfileitrmfactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.servletfileupload;
```

I have my got the below jar in web-inf/lib path in project

Commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
Commons-up-2.4.jar

Please guide me to get the project compiled. I am clueless since I have no idea about java and trying to run the project and debug .

Comment: What is the error you are getting, it can't find those classes? You need to either specify a class to import, e.g. `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUpload`, or import all the classes in that package using `*`, e.g. `org.apache.commons.fileupload.*`

Comment: Right click your project > Properties > Libraries. Can you tell me what you see?

Comment: `Import` should be `import`

Comment: @lxcky , i right click on project > properties > libraries and i am seeing that  is empty with browse option on right to that. I did right on root project level and checked this.

Comment: @ScaryWombat , Yes that is just typo in stack overflow. In actual code it is lower case "import".

Comment: so going back to @Fodder comment - what error are you getting?

Comment: @Fodder , I am getting error in start in which org is marked with red underline. Anyways i tried what you suggested as well still it did not work.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, the error is as below

Comment: C:\Users\ASHOKKUMAR\Downloads\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing (1)\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing\src\java\com\eyeopen\sources\upload1.java:14: error: package org.apache.commons.fileupload does not exist
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;

Comment: C:\Users\ASHOKKUMAR\Downloads\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing (1)\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing\src\java\com\eyeopen\sources\upload1.java:16: error: package org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk does not exist
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;

Comment: C:\Users\ASHOKKUMAR\Downloads\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing (1)\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing\src\java\com\eyeopen\sources\upload1.java:17: error: package org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet does not exist
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

Comment: C:\Users\ASHOKKUMAR\Downloads\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing (1)\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing\src\java\com\eyeopen\sources\upload1.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
            List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
  symbol:   class FileItem
  location: class upload1

Comment: C:\Users\ASHOKKUMAR\Downloads\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing (1)\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing\nbproject\build-impl.xml:874: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\ASHOKKUMAR\Downloads\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing (1)\A Survey of Proxy Re-Encryption for Secure Data Sharing in Cloud Computing\nbproject\build-impl.xml:296: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: Have you tried importing the jars using netbeans? Please refer to [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43881981/3943327).

Comment: @lxcky , Tried the thing suggested by you, i added jars and did clean & build project still no luck

Comment: Any other thoughts ? It will be really helpful.

Comment: Try looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807395/jars-added-to-web-inf-lib-doesnt-get-recognized-when-i-try-to-import-them-say

Comment: @Fodder , tried it, no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

Import your jar files the proper way.

- Right click your project >
- Properties >
- Libraries

Then click the `Add Jar/Folder` button to import the jars you need.

After this, clean and build the project (Right click > Clean and Build), and try to run it.

Comment: Tried the thing suggested by you, i added jars and did clean & build project still no luck

Answer (score -1):

Your setup probably has some sort of error to find out the path to those .jar files, it is common to happen when you've got the files imported in a wrong way.

I'd like to suggest to you to use Maven. Maven is a dependency manager and will be in charge to manage all your dependencies along the build of your project among all other features. It is easy to use and will make your life a lot easier. 
Here you have two links, one if you'd like to understand better how it works (https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/) and the another to help you to build your Maven project (https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/). I don't use NetBeans IDE but it probably has support for Maven, but in case it doesn't, you could look for a plugin.

Hope it helps.