# log4j-Logger not writing to log-file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

For my netbeans java web application I want to use a logger for debugging.
To this end I included log4j-1.2.16.jar in my Libraries:

[image]

In the folder "Source Packages" I created a folder called "Logging". Inside this folder I put the following servlet (which initialises the logger when the application is started):

package Logging;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender;

public class InitLog4j extends HttpServlet {

   public void init() {
        String initPath = getInitParameter("logPath");
        String logPath = "/WEB-INF/logs/error.log";
        if (initPath != null) logPath = initPath;
        FileAppender appender = getAppender(logPath);
        if (appender == null) return;
        initLogger(null, appender, Level.INFO);
  }

  private FileAppender getAppender(String fileName) {
    RollingFileAppender appender = null;
    try {
      appender = new RollingFileAppender(
          new PatternLayout("%-5p %c %t%n%29d - %m%n"),
          getServletContext().getRealPath(fileName),
          true);
      appender.setMaxBackupIndex(5);
      appender.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println(
          "Could not create appender for " 
          + fileName + ":"
          + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return appender;
  }

  private void initLogger(String name, 
                          FileAppender appender, 
                          Level level) 
  {
    Logger logger;
    if (name == null) {
      logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
    } else {
      logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
    }
    logger.setLevel(level);
    logger.addAppender(appender);
    logger.info("Starting " + logger.getName());
  }


}
```

In my web.xnl file I included the following lines:

[image]

Finally I created a log file (inside a logs folder inside the WEB-INF folder):

[image]

I then created a logger inside the "controller" class. This logger was supposed to write a text message to the file error.log:

[image]

However, when I run the application (which creates an http request, which - as you can see from the picture above - is supposed to trigger the logger), nothing is written to the error.log file. It's as empty as before.

Why is my logger not writing to the log file?

******************************UPDATE*************************************

Adding jar-files to the lib-folder is not possible:

[image]

Only adding them to the Libraries folder would be possible:

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you are initializing log4j this (rather hard) way instead of  a log4j.xml on the classpath?

Comment: I don't think you need a servlet to do this for you. As @jingx suggests, you could initialize log4j on the classpath. Take a look at [this doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j)

Comment: @Ishnark As requested in the guide under the link, I downloaded log4j.
I am supposed to put this into  a "WEB-INF/classes" folder. Hence, I created a "classes" folder inside of "WEB-INF" ... However, I cannot add jar-files to this folder (when I right-click on the classes-folder, no such option is given)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I thought you wanted to log your tomcat. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

*Working Approach* (It works, but it's not the best)

- If you just want to log this one application then put the `log4j.jar` and `log4j.properties` into `WEB-INF/lib`. You can't put `.jar` files in the `WEB-INF /classes`. That's reserved for `.class` files.

  - `log4j.jar` and `log4j.properties` files have to be loaded by the same classloader, so *both* files have to be in the lib directory for the classloader to pick it up.
- Alternatively, if you want to use the same log configuration for all apps in the project, you can shift these two files to the `Tomcat/lib` directory.

*Better Approach*

It's not a good practice to put a non-jar file in the lib directory. The `log4j.properties` is a configuration file. We can instead do the following:

1. As we did before, keep the `log4j.jar` in the 'WEB-INF/lib' directory.
2. Then place the `log4j.properties` in a conf directory (either 'Tomcat/conf', or 'WEB-INF/conf').
3. Then, in each class that uses a logger, you can do this: ClassThatUsesLogger.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf/log4j.properties");

Comment: The thing is: I can't add jar-files to the lib folder inside the WEB-IN-folder ... I could add them to the Libraries folder ... but if  I have to add them to the lib folder (which I created on request by you), it doesn't work

Comment: you can't drop the files in via the Finder (assuming this is a mac)?

Comment: I dropped the files into the lib folder ... then I clean-built the project ... the jar files are not shown in netbeans inside the lib-folder (although they actually are inside this folder) ... when I run my application, again the logger does not write anything to the log file

Comment: Hmm I'm not too familiar with NetBeans but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807395/jars-added-to-web-inf-lib-doesnt-get-recognized-when-i-try-to-import-them-say). Try adding the jar to your project classpath as well and maybe it will show up?

Comment: the link says: "for netbeans:

in the project properties window click libraries in the left panel. In the right panel add it to the compile classpath"

I don't have "libraries" folder, only "Libraries"

Comment: assuming "libraries" is meant what are "left "and "right " panel supposed to mean?

Comment: if I right-click "Libraries", I get the options you can see in the picture I posted  in the question

Comment: Wait a second, when you add a Jar to the "Libraries" by right click, you can browse to the location of the JAR file on your computer, which in this case, will be the WEB-INF/lib jar, and then click Open. Then the jars should be on your classpath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147402/discussion-between-ishnark-and-steady-progress).